# JS: Reversing a string using nested loop does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, nested, reverse

I have written a function called `reverseStr` that takes in a string as a parameter and returns the string but with the characters in reverse.

For example: `reverseStr('bootcamp');` => `'pmactoob'`

Following is my program:

```js
function reverseStr(str)
{
 var splitStr = str.split("");
 console.log(splitStr);
 var reverseString = [];
 for(var i = 0; i <= splitStr.length -1 ; i++)
 {
  for(var j = splitStr.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
  {
   reverseString[i] = splitStr[j]
  }
 }

 return reverseString.toString().replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
}
```

If I run the function `reverseStr("bootcamp")` it returns `bbbbbbbb`.
Does anyone see a problem with the code?

Note: I DONOT WANT TO USE `REVERSE()` BUILT-IN FUNCTION

However, I found success with the following code **but still need an answer to my initial question**

```js
function reverseStr(str)
{
 var splitStr = str.split("");
 reverseStr = "";
 for(var i = splitStr.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i = i - 1)
 {
  reverseStr += splitStr[i];
 }

 return reverseStr;
}
```

Comment: Do you still need an answer to your initial question?

Comment: yes please @Aydin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to double-iterate through the characters, i.e., do not need to nest `for` loops. Iterate once and grab the chars in reverse order, like this:

```
function reverseStr(str)
{
    var splitStr = str.split("");
    console.log(splitStr);
    var reverseString = [];
    for(var i = 0, j=splitStr.length-1; i <= splitStr.length -1 ; i++, j--)
    {
            reverseString[i] = splitStr[j]
    }

    return reverseString.toString().replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
}
```

You can see that here the loop goes on for as long as `i <= splitStr.length -1`,ie, length of the string. This is sufficient to get the mirroring character (`i` versus `Array.length-i`).

Here is a working snippet to demo:

```js
var reverseStr = function(str) {
  let result = String();
  for(let i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result += str.charAt(i);
  }
  return result.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
}
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.result').text(reverseStr($('#str').val()));
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="str">
    <button>Reverse it</button>
    <div class="result"></div>
```

Perhaps a more elegant way to achieve the same (apart from *Array.prototype.reverse()*) would be to use `String.prototype.chatAt()`. This would avoid two conversions to and from an array, and also save you one variable. Granted, the code is much shorter and more obvious in what it is doing.

```js
var reverseStr = function(str) {
  let result = String(); // An empty string to store the result
  for(let i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { // Iterate backwards thru the chars and add to the result string
    result += str.charAt(i);
  }
  return result.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, ''); // Original return method of the author
}
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.result').text(reverseStr($('#str').val()));
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="str">
    <button>Reverse it</button>
    <div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting an error after `i <= splitStr.length -1 ;`

Comment: I added another way of doing what your code was supposed to do - it might be a cleaner way of achieving the task. It is not a direct answer to your question - just pointing out, someone may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your nested `for` loop runs its whole course before it returns to the outer `for` loop. So, it just repeats one character the amount of times equal to the length. Instead of having another `for` loop, just add a simple counter for `j` like `j++` inside your outer `for` loop and use that value with the `i` value.

Answer (score 0):

To the original poster, consider this:

If you know the length of the original string, you therefore know the offset of that last position within the original string.

Iterate through the original string in reverse order, appending the current position's value to a new string. The new string would be the reverse of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Aydin's example is essentially correct. Here's my very similar version, with comments:

```
function reverseString(inputString) {
    // create a new empty string
    var newString = "";

    // iterate through the characters of the string in reverse order,
    // appending to the new string
    for (var i = inputString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newString += inputString[i];
    }

    return newString;
}

console.log(reverseString('bootcamp'));
```